# Objective C mutables array extract from indexes

Tags: objective-c, arrays, indexing

Hi I have two arrays one has 200 + objects ( never changes) and another which is an array of integers ( as NSNumber objects) what is the easiest way to create a third array which will be an array of all objects from array 1 that are included in the array of indexes from array 2?

Comment: If you can use an `NSIndexSet` instead of the second array. Then it's just a `[array1 objectsAtIndexes:indexSet]`

Comment: I am seeing two different solutions, both voted-up!!! can u give us examples to understand what u actually want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to convert the array of indexes to an `NSIndexSet` and then use `objectsAtIndexes:`

```
NSArray *objects = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G"];
NSArray *indexArray = @[@(0), @(2), @(6)];

NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
for (NSNumber *number in indexArray) {
    [indexSet addIndex:[number unsignedIntegerValue]];
}
NSArray *filtered = [objects objectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
```

Result: `A, C, G`

Of course, if you can, it would be better to directly use an index set, instead of an array.

Or you could just use a simple loop.

```
NSMutableArray *filtered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
                             initWithCapacity:indexArray.length];
for (NSNumber *number in indexArray) {
    [filtered addObject:objects[[number unsignedIntegerValue]]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks this answer was just what i was looking for.  Last question my array i get back (filtered) becomes an imutable array with the above code, how do i generate it as a mutable array so that i can then further filter it if need be?

Comment: `NSMutableArray *filtered = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[objects objectsAtIndexes:indexSet]];`

Answer (score 1):

You can create sets and use the methods on `NSMutableSet`

```
NSArray *array1 = @[ @1, @2, @3 ];
NSArray *array2 = @[ @2 ];

NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
[set intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:array2]];

NSLog(@"%@", set.allObjects);

//=>( 2 )
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's looking for.

Comment: @DrummerB ... but actually the correct answer if you read the question word by word.

Comment: I think he would have said "200+ numbers" instead of "objects" if he meant that, but you're right, it's definitely not a clearly formulated question.